# In Azure, I can create a web app or a web app with sql. What if I already have a SQL database?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I already have Azure sql databases.  If I create a wep app will I be able to connect to them in PHP?  Or do I have to specify a web app + SQL in order to get the MSSQL library with PHP?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Webapp is just like any normal application and your Azure Sql database is just like any normal database - yes, you can connect them as long as the firewall rules and accounts are set up accordingly. The WebApp + SQL is just a comfort feature in case you need to initialise both.